# MySQL can't start after transfering from old to new server

Tags: mysql

I recently transferred mysql data from an old ssh server to a new ssh server using rsync, the transfer was from files in old server `/var/lib/mysql/` to `/var/lib/mysql/` in new server , the move was good. After that I tried to restart the mysql server using `sudo service mysql restart`.
I got this error :

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I did a systemctl status mysql.service after and got this :

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-06-23 20:44:07 UTC; 1min 7s ago
  Process: 16490 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 16466 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11702 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

So, I did some research and set ownership of the mysql using `chown mysql:mysql -R /var/lib/mysql/` but it didn't make any difference.

I need some assistance to solve this issue. Is there perhaps something that I missed to do?

Thanks!

Comment: look in the mysql error log and see which problem it has, there should be also an explanation

Comment: a) hope you did the rsync while the server was stopped, if not, stop it, and do it again. b) what is the specific mysql version on the old and new. c) like ^ error log. Either `journalctl -n 300 -u mysql.sevice` r a configured `/var/log/mysql/*.{err,log}` or however its configured.

Comment: sql dump and import?